# grails hasMany with POJO domain class

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, pojo

I have the following annotated POJO placed in /src/java :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class A {
    @Id 
    public String id; 
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
    List<A> As;
    ...
}
```

I declared the class in hibernate.cfg.xml and was able to use dynamic scaffolding to generate a crud interface for this domain.

Then I tried using domain A with a hasMany felationship from a grails domain :

```
class B {
   List<A> children=[]
   static hasMany = [ children :  mypackage.A ]
}
```

I can't runApp anymore, grails is complaining about :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Missing type or column for column[childrens_A]
on domain[B] referencing[mypackage.A]
```

Comment: don't place it in src/java/. it's as simple as that

Comment: do you mean to move the POJO from src/java/ to grails-app/domain ? Just tried it, It didn't change anything.

Comment: make a plain groovy domain class w/o all those funny annotations

Comment: Yes that would work but i wanted to use the pojos as described here : [link](http://grails.org/doc/2.4.3/guide/hibernate.html)

Answer (score 0):

https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11727

Apparently, domain can be in hibernate or gorm syntaxe but not both.